# show that $\exists C \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C |x-y|^{\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ absolutely continuous, $1 < p < \infty$ and $ f' \in L^{p}([a,b])$. Show that there exists a $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C|x - y|^{\alpha}$

everywhere $x,y \in [a,b]$, where $\alpha = 1- 1/p$.

I don't even really know where to start with this one. I am looking at definitons of absolutely continuous functions and $L^{p}$ spaces but can't see anything helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is AC, we can write $f(x)-f(y)=\int_y^xf'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$. Without loss of generality, suppose $x>y$. By Hölder's inequality, we have
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le\int_y^x|f'(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t\le\left(\int_y^x|f'(t)|^p\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_y^x\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1-1/p}\le\|f'\|_p(x-y)^{\alpha}.$$